# How to remove actionbar's shadow after hide it

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am trying to hide my actionBar when the DrawerNavigator is opened, but a 'shadow' stays.
For hidding the acctionBar I use a `DrawerListener` and when `onDrawerOpened` is trigged I use `getSupportActionBar().hide();` to hide it.

[image: before hidding drawer]

[image: after done]

I tried to set `getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);`, but it doesn't work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
app:elevation="0dp"
>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_drawer_button"
    android:layout_width="24dp"
    android:layout_height="24dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_bars"/>
       ...

</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

And my `AppTheme` theme is:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: `actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#00000000")));` Can you try to set its color and transparency ?

Comment: It doesn't work @Yahya

Comment: Other options would be `setTranslationZ()` and `bringToFront()` for the `DrawerLayout`

Comment: using `setTranslationZ(float)` which number do you thing is a good chance?

Comment: `setTranslationZ()` and `bringToFront()` for `DrawerLayout` doesn't work.

Comment: maybe `Integer.MAX_VALUE`?

Comment: doesn't work too

Comment: if `setDrawerElevation()` , `setZ`  , `setTranslationZ()` and `bringToFront()` together don't work, then I run out of solutions. Sorry

Comment: one last thing, have you tried `<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
            app:elevation="0dp">` Now I really run out of solutions if this doesn't work.

Comment: does'nt work, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Please add this in your Java activity code(f.e. main activity):

```
getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I have told that in my question, but I am going to edit it

Comment: Can you try set elevation to 0, and then after this hide?

Comment: Can you upload your Java code, or give link to your project repo?